# PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePayments() returning true when Info.plist capability is not there

Tags: ios, applepay

The `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePayments()` call returns true even if the `Info.plist` does not include a `<dict> ... <key>com.apple.developer.in-app-payments</key> </dict>`. In other words the capability switch in Xcode is off. How can I verify this exists before rendering the button.

Comment: You should be able to just read the key from the info.plist at runtime - https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-read-your-apps-version-from-your-infoplist-file

Comment: @Paulw11okay will give that shot great idea!

Comment: @Paulw11I looked at my git diff wrong its actually updating a appname.entitlements file which doesn't seem to be readable